# $E_n =\lbrace X_n > X_m \ \forall m < n \rbrace $ are independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm stuck with this exercise.

Suppose $(X_n)$ are independent random variables defined on $(\Omega, \mathfrak{F}, P)$ with the same p.d.f.

Let $E_1 = \Omega$ and for $n \geq 2$ $$E_n =\lbrace X_n > X_m \ \forall m < n \rbrace $$ Then $E_1, E_2 , \ldots $ are independent with $P(E_n) = \frac{1}{n} $.

How to proceed ?

Comment: It it clear to you that $P(E_n)=\frac{1}{n}$?

Comment: I don't believe that this is true. For instance, $X_n:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $X_n(\omega) = 0$ for all $\omega \in \Omega$ is a perfectly good set of independent random variables. A less trivial example would be if $\Omega = \{0, 1, 2\}^\mathbb{N}$ with the uniform measure, and $X_n(\omega) = \omega_n$, the nth coordinate of $\omega$. There $P(X_1 > X_2) = 1/3$. You need $P(X_i=X_j) = 0$ to make what you are trying to prove true.

Comment: @user24142 $P(X_i = X_j) = 0$ is subsumed by the assumption that the $X_n$s have a density.

Comment: @snarski I think that depends on whether we let out density functions have linear combinations of dirac deltas, but I belive you're right here.

Comment: A "p.d.f." is by definition a density with respect to Lebesgue measure, so it is non-singular w.r.t. Leb.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $X_{n}$ are independent and absolutely continuous. This gives
us the liberty to start with the assumption that $X_{n}\neq X_{m}$
for each pair $\left(n,m\right)$ where $n\neq m$ without any loss
of generality.

Note that the event $E_n$ can be interpreted as: $X_n$ is the "greatest" of $X_1,\dots,X_n$.

The $X_i$ (for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$) all have *equal* chances to be the "greatest" here and one of them a.s. is the greatest. That gives $P(E_n)=\frac{1}{n}$

Every order $X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\cdots<X_{\sigma(n)}$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation on $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ has the same probability to occur and there are $n!$ possibilities. So denoting  $B_{\sigma}:=\{X_{\sigma(1)}<X_{\sigma(2)}<\cdots<X_{\sigma(n)}\}$ we have $P(B_{\sigma})=\frac{1}{n!}$ for each $\sigma$. Note that $\sigma\neq\sigma'\Rightarrow B_{\sigma}\cap B_{\sigma'}=\emptyset$.

It is to be shown that for each $n\in\mathbb N$ we have $P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\right)=P\left(A_{1}\right)\cdots P\left(A_{n}\right)$
if $A_{i}\in\left\{ E_{i},E_{i}^{c}\right\} $ for $i=1,\dots,n$.
Using induction on $n$ it is enough to prove that $P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\cap E_{n+1}\right)=P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\right)P\left(E_{n+1}\right)$
since that implies that also $P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\cap E_{n+1}^{c}\right)=P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\right)P\left(E_{n+1}^{c}\right)$.

We have: $P\left(B_{\sigma}\cap E_{n+1}\right)=P(\left\{ X_{\sigma\left(1\right)}<\cdots<X_{\sigma\left(n\right)}<X_{n+1}\right\}) =\frac{1}{\left(n+1\right)!}=P\left(B_{\sigma}\right).\frac{1}{n+1}=P\left(B_{\sigma}\right)P\left(E_{n+1}\right)$

Now realize that every event $A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}$ can be written as a finite union of disjoint
events $B_{\sigma}$. An immediate consequence is that $P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\cap E_{n+1}\right)=P\left(A_{1}\cap\cdots\cap A_{n}\right)P\left(E_{n+1}\right)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Nicely done. You are missing a $P$ on the set $\{X_{\sigma(1)} < ... < X_{\sigma(n)} < X_{n+1}\}$ in the penultimate paragraph, after "We have:".

Comment: @snarski Thank you (also for the compliment). Repaired.

Comment: @drhab Can you explain to me why we can start with $X_n \not = X_m$ for distinct n and m without loss of generality?

Comment: @pm021 If $X,Y$ are independent random variables and at least one of them
is absolutely continuous (i.e. has a PDF) then it can be shown that
$P\left(X=Y\right)=0$ or equivalently $P\left(X\neq Y\right)=1$.
In the context of my answer this leads to $P\left(F\right)=1$ for
$F:=\left\{ X_{1},\dots,X_{n}\text{ are distinct}\right\}$. Then
$P\left(E\right)=P\left(E\mid F\right)$ is true for *any* event $E$.

Comment: @drhab Is it enough for one of them to have a PDF? OR do we actually need both of them to have their PDFs?

Comment: @pm021 One of them having a PDF is enough. You can even do it with less than
that. If $P\left\{ X=x\right\} =0$ for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and
$X,Y$ are independent random variables then $P\left(X=Y\right)=\int P\left(X=Y\mid Y=y\right)F_{Y}\left(y\right)=\int P\left(X=y\right)F_{Y}\left(y\right)=0$
since the integrand is the zero map. So actually it is allready enough
if the distribution of $X$ is *continuous*. This will be the case if
$X$ has a PDF. For "being continuous" having a PDF is sufficient, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

From the onset, due to the $X_n$ being i.i.d. continuous random variables, $X_n{}={}X_{n'}$ for $n \ne n^{'}$ are zero probability events. Consequently, we concentrate on orderings of these random variables.

For a given $n$, there are $n!$ exhaustive ways of ordering the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_n$. By symmetry (from the random variables being i.i.d.) each of these orderings is identical in probability, a probability which we label $\rho_n$, and exhaustiveness implies

> $$
> (n!)\rho_n{}={}1\iff\rho_n{}={}\frac{1}{n!}\,.
> $$

And, since by fixing $X_n$ to be the largest of these, there are $(n-1)!$ ways of arranging the order of the remaining random variables, we have
$$
P\left(E_n\right){}={}\rho_n(n-1)!{}={}\frac{1}{n!}(n-1)!{}={}\dfrac{1}{n}\,.
$$

Finally, choose any finite set of distinct natural numbers $n_1<\ldots<n_m$ and observe that:

(i) There are $(n_1-1)!$ distinct ways of ordering the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_{n_{1}-1}$, keeping $X_{n_1}$ maximum.

(ii) For each such ordering of $X_1,\ldots,X_{n_{1}-1},\,\,$ there are $\dfrac{(n_2-1)!}{n_1!}$ ways of ordering the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_{n_{2}-1},\,\,$ keeping $X_{n_{2}}$ maximum.

Analogous dependent counts hold for $\,n_3\,\,$ (for each "$n_2-1$" ordering), $\,n_4\,$ (for each  "$n_3-1$" ordering), and so on till $\,n_m\,$ (for each "$n_{m-1}-1$" ordering).

(iii) There are $\,\,n_m!\,\,$ exhaustive ways in which the random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_{n_m}$ may be ordered, so $\rho_{n_m}{}={}\dfrac{1}{n_m!}$.

Therefore,

> $$
> \begin{eqnarray*}
> P\left(E_{n_1},\ldots,E_{n_m}\right)&{}={}&\rho_{n_m}\dfrac{(n_m-1)!}{n_{m-1}!}\ldots\dfrac{(n_2-1)!}{n_1!}(n_1-1)!\newline
> &&\newline
> &{}={}&\dfrac{1}{n_m!}\dfrac{(n_m-1)!}{n_{m-1}!}\ldots\dfrac{(n_2-1)!}{n_1!}(n_1-1)!\newline
> &&\newline
> &{}={}&\dfrac{1}{n_1\ldots n_m}\newline
> &&\newline
> &{}={}&P\left(E_{n_1}\right)\ldots P\left(E_{n_m}\right)\,.
> \end{eqnarray*}
> $$

Comment: @drhab, :) Ouch,...thanks for setting me straight! I am curious, though. At the risk of being laughed at, why isn't the following Wikipedia entry applicable here as a definition of independence between events? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_%28probability_theory%29#More_than_two_events

Comment: I think I am the one that be laughed at. My first comment on your question is wrong I think. In my deleted answer I proved that $P(E_1\cap\cdots\cap E_n)=P(E_1)\times\cdots\times P(E_n)$. That is not enough, but I realize now that you have done more than that. You can have $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac12$, $P(A\cap B)=\frac14$ and $P(A\cap B\cap C)=\frac18$ without independence, but if you also have $P(A\cap C)=P(B\cap C)=\frac14$ then there must be independence. Sorry for this (I feel a bit stupid). I am not completely sure yet, but will let you know if I come to other insights.

Comment: @drhab, :) That's okay, I agree to do no laughing if you don't. Thanks for being neighbourly, and please let me know if you spot a flaw in the answer.

Comment: I will take away my first comment now. I am somehow "exposing" myself there and of course I don't like that ;).