# Does this argument suffice to show a "record" occurs at time n with probability 1/n?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I think it does, but, in addition to checking for correctness, I'd like to know what other argument we might use.

> Let $X_1, X_2,...X_n$ be be a sequence of independent identically distributed continuous random variables.  We say a record occurs at time $n$ if $ X_n \gt \max(X_1, .\dots ,X_{n−1})$.
>
> Show $P${Record occurs at time n}=$1/n$.

Since the distributions are identical and independent, then all the $n!$ ways to order the $n$ $X_i's$ are equally as probable. Since there are exactly $(n-1)!$ ways to order the $n$ $X_i's$ such that the $n$th element is the largest, then $P${Record occurs at time n}=$(n-1)!/n!=1/n$.

Comment: An even simpler argument : Since $X_m=X_n$ has probability $0$ for $m\ne n$, one of the numbers $X_1,...,X_n$ must be the biggest. The probability, that it is $X_n$, is $\frac{1}{n}$ due to symmetry.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1124777/75923) you will find a question in the same line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is okay. Another (and more direct and elegant) way is stating that under these conditions for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ each of the $X_i$ has equal chance to be the largest of the set $\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$. This especially because without loss of generality we can assume here that the iid $X_i$ are all distinct. So the probability that $X_n$ is the largest of $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is $\frac{1}{n}$.