# Probability a record occurs at time $n$ using cdf

Tags: probability

Question: if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are iid continuous random variables, what is $P(X_n > \max\{X_1,\ldots,{X_{n-1}}\})$?

I know there is a very simple way to obtain the answer, like in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129393/does-this-argument-suffice-to-show-a-record-occurs-at-time-n-with-probability). However, I went a more challenging route when I attempted this problem, and I'm unsure where it failed. My Approach:

\begin{align}
P(X_n > \max\{X_1,\ldots,{X_{n-1}}\}) &= P(X_n > X_i \;\forall i\in[n-1]) \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} P(X_n > X_i) & \text{because of independence} \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} P(F(X_n) > F(X_i)) & \text{where $F$ is the cdf} \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} \int_0^1 \int_x^1 dydx \\
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} 1/2 \\
&=1/2^{n-1}
\end{align}

which is not the correct answer $1/n$. What did I do wrong? I am new to probability so I'm likely misunderstanding something fundamental.

Comment: $X_n > X_i$ is not independent of $X_n > X_j$ - both often happen when $X_n$ is large

Comment: ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Henry points out, the events $\{X_n > X_1\}, \{X_n > X_2\} ,\ldots$ are not actually independent due to the common dependence on $X_n$.

If you wish you could proceed as follows.
Note that
\begin{align}
P(t > \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}\})
&= \prod_{i=1}^{n-1} P(X_i < t) = F(t)^{n-1}.
\end{align}
The above quantity appears if you take the probability you are interested in and condition on $X_n$.
\begin{align}
P(X_n > \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}\})
&= E[P(X_n > \max\{X_1, \ldots, X_{n-1}\} \mid X_n)]
\\
&= E[F(X_n)^{n-1}]
\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(t)^{n-1} f(t) \, dt
\\
&= \left[\frac{1}{n} F(u)^n\right]_{u=-\infty}^\infty
\\
&= \frac{1}{n}.
\end{align}